# What is the equivalent Anylogic function "zidz" in Java?

Tags: java, function, anylogic

In Anylogic there is a built-in function [zidz](http://www.anylogic.com/anylogic/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/functions/zidz.html), which does the following:

```
zidz(double a, double b)
```

> Description
>
> Tries to divide the first argument by the second. If the result is infinity or not a number, returns 0, otherwise returns the division result.

My question for you guys is: do you know a function that does the same operation but in Java?

I've searched and come up with [`Math#IEEEremainder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#IEEEremainder%28double,%20double%29), but I don't think it does the exact same thing as 'zidz'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't one in the common set of libraries. That's not to say there is nobody in the world who has written and published one, but the function is so trivial as to be unlikely to be included in a Java library.

Comment: Thanks @Dancrumb. Yeah it is indeed trivial xD, just wanted to know if I was missing something in the Java library. Thanks again.